# Wait for react state/props to update before using data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using react-redux with persist-store in my react app. Once the user logs in, the state contains user data i want to use to customize the app and display their name and other info. It works ok unless someone refreshes the page.

I added persist store because i would lose the state values on a refresh and it would show not authenticated. Now it works but there seems to be a delay before the state gets restored. So if i try to use the user's name in a component, on a refresh it will crash saying it is undefined. But after a few secs the data is available as i can see it in the console.log(this.props)

Right now i am using ternary operators for all these values and it's an ok solution but i was wondering if there is a way to wait for the data before it get's used?

Here's one of my component

```
TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

class UserProfile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchData } = this.props;
    fetchData(data);
  }

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { login } = this.props;
    const title = brand.name + ' - Profile';
    const description = brand.desc;
    const { dataProps, classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    const name = login.user.name === undefined ? '' : shortenName(login.user.name);
    const group = login.user.groups === undefined ? '' : login.user.groups[0].name;
    const role =
      login.user.role === undefined
        ? ''
        : login.user.role.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + login.user.role.slice(1);
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
          <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
        </Helmet>
        <Cover
          coverImg={bgCover}
          avatar={dummy.user.avatar}
          name={name}
          desc={`${user.role.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user.role.slice(1)} - ${group}`}
        />
        <AppBar position="static" className={classes.profileTab}>
          <Hidden mdUp>
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              variant="fullWidth"
              indicatorColor="primary"
              textColor="primary"
              centered
            >
              <Tab icon={<AccountCircle />} />
              <Tab icon={<SupervisorAccount />} />
              <Tab icon={<Favorite />} />
              <Tab icon={<PhotoLibrary />} />
            </Tabs>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden smDown>
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              variant="fullWidth"
              indicatorColor="primary"
              textColor="primary"
              centered
            >
              <Tab icon={<AccountCircle />} label="ABOUT" />
              <Tab icon={<SupervisorAccount />} label="0 CONNECTIONS" />
              <Tab icon={<Favorite />} label="0 FAVORITES" />
              <Tab icon={<PhotoLibrary />} label="0 ALBUMS" />
            </Tabs>
          </Hidden>
        </AppBar>
        {value === 0 && (
          <TabContainer>
            <About data={dataProps} />
          </TabContainer>
        )}
        {value === 1 && (
          <TabContainer>
            <Connection />
          </TabContainer>
        )}
        {value === 2 && (
          <TabContainer>
            <Favorites />
          </TabContainer>
        )}
        {value === 3 && (
          <TabContainer>
            <Albums />
          </TabContainer>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

UserProfile.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dataProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const reducer = 'socmed';
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  force: state, // force state from reducer
  dataProps: state.getIn([reducer, 'dataTimeline']),
  login: state.get('login'),
});

const constDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: bindActionCreators(fetchAction, dispatch),
});

const UserProfileMapped = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  constDispatchToProps,
)(UserProfile);

export default withStyles(styles)(UserProfileMapped);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ways to achieve this:

1. Continue with your current approach, as using conditionals in `render()` is a valid and idiomatic way to display data in React.
2. If `fetchData` returns a promise, keep track of a loading state, and don't render anything until the promise completes.

```js
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      email: '',
      value: 0,
      isLoading: true,
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
   const { fetchData } = this.props;
   fetchData(data)
      .then(() => {
         this.setState({isLoading: false})
      })
      .catch((e) => {
         console.error(e);
         this.setState({isLoading: false})
      });
}

render() {
   const {isLoading} = this.state;
   
   if (isLoading) {
      return null;
   }

   ...
   // Remove the conditional around user
   ...
}
```